# Move component anywhere on page in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular component called A in another component called B. I need to move A component anywhere on component B. Component A is a div element like popup where we can close popup.

Comment: do you mean drag and pan ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-boostrap-draggable

refer this link mat be it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to drag and drop components, right? If yes, have a look at https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview